# Jssor Images Too Zoomed In

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

I'm using [the Jssor library](http://jssor.com) to create an image slider. I set $FillMode to 4 so that the images should fit in the container, but it didn't work. This is what one of the images looks like:

[image]

So I tried every other mode and didn't see any changes.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jssor.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 
    <div id="main">
       <h1>Swipe right for yes and left for no.</h1>
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 300px; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 300px; height: 600px;">
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/indian.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/hamburger.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/italian-pizza.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/hummus.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/pie.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/montecristo.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/eclairs.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
    </div> 
    <script>jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');</script>
</div>
    </div> 
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {
            $FillMode: 4,
        };                            
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);

        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales
        //while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = $('#slider1_container').parent().width();
            if (parentWidth) {
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
            }
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
        //Scale slider after document ready
        ScaleSlider();
        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added a max-width and max-height to my CSS, like this:

```
<style>
#slider1_container img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 
    <div id="main">
       <h1>Swipe right for yes and left for no.</h1>
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 300px; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 300px; height: 600px;">
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/indian.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/hamburger.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/italian-pizza.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/hummus.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/pie.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/montecristo.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
        <div><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/eclairs.jpg" alt="" title=""/></div> 
    </div> 
    <script>jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');</script>
</div>
    </div> 
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {
            $FillMode: 4,
        };                            
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);

        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales
        //while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = $('#slider1_container').parent().width();
            if (parentWidth) {
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
            }
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
        //Scale slider after document ready
        ScaleSlider();
        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the images are still too zoomed in, even with this exact code copied and pasted.

Comment: I was able to get it by adding:

'<style>
#slider1_container img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
</style>'

Comment: I guess the best way is to set $FillMode to 0, 1 or 2

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for FillMode which is 5. That says (contain for large image, actual size for small image). Haven't tried it but it should work.

Reference [Link](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have the very same problem a couple of years later.
Don't really want to hack around with css, I assume it must be a bug in either how $FillMode works, OR there must be some non-obvious container/conflict with it.
Definitely never 'contain's images, tried all $FillMode s

Note: using latest version as of 2019.06.28.